# C# .net Core JWT Token Get values

Tags: c#, .net-core, jwt

I have some `Claim` from `JwtSecurityToken` that look like this:

```
{  
   "profile":{  
      "roles":{  
         "Rolename":{  
            "Type":27
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I need get value `Type` (now it's 27)

Rolename it's name the role - it can be different (and there can be more than one role)

Task for me it get name the role and get value of `Type`

How I do it:

```
JwtSecurityTokenHandler handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
JwtSecurityToken tokenS = handler.ReadToken(token) as JwtSecurityToken;
string profile = tokenS.Claims.First(claim => claim.Type == "profile").Value;
JObject o = JObject.Parse(profile);
string cardType = o.SelectToken("$.roles." + "Rolename" + ".Type").ToString();
```

It's work well, but I don't know how to take rolename and how to be when I'll have more that one role

Comment: I would make "roles" an array if I were you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is always one role you can do this:

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(profile);
var role = ((JObject)o["roles"]).Properties().First();

string roleName = role.Name;

int cardType = (int)role.Value["Type"];
```

if there can be several roles you can loop through an array of `JProperty` like this:

```
var roles = ((JObject)o["roles"]).Properties();
foreach (var role in roles)
{
    string roleName = role.Name;

    int cardType = (int)role.Value["Type"];
}
```

Comment: It's good answer but I can't change the structure of token, I need to work with what is exists

Comment: I've also updated your answer. Because `profile = {"roles":{"Rolename":{"Type":27}}}.` There is no structure `["profile"]` inside profile. And in runtime was NullReferenceException. I've only removed `["profile"]` and now everything work well. really thank you

Answer (score 0):

Roles as in plural should be an array.
Then you can get all the values in that array the way you want with a loop.
Example:

```
var roleTypes = new List<string>();
foreach (var role in profile.roles)
{
    //populate a list
}
```

Comment: Roles as in plural should be an array - pls show example

Comment: @Igor [JSON arrays](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp) (and for completeness: [JSON objects](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp))

Comment: @john Type in role depends on Role and must be in Role - pls show how it could be look

Comment: Do you mean when you have something like this: 
{  
   "profile":{  
      "roles":[
          {  
            "Rolename1":{  
            "Type":27
            }
         },
         {
            "Rolename2":{  
            "Type":28
            }
         }]
      }
   }

Comment: @Phael I think he means `{"profile":{"roles":{"Rolename":{"Type":27},"Rolename2":{"Type":1923892}}}}` .... or not. Who knows? The question is unclear.